# Backgrounded CBPeripheral doesn't stay readable

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, ios-bluetooth

I have an app that broadcasts a `CBPeripheral` with a small amount of text.
I use the `bluetooth-peripheral` background mode to allow it to broadcast in the background.

When I scan from another device, in the foreground it works fine. I detect the peripheral, connect, discover the services then read the data from the service.

In the background however, there is something not quite right. I scan for peripherals with my service, and it finds it fine. I connect which also goes fine. I then `discoverServices` with my service which also goes fine as the `didDiscoverServices` callback is called. However in this callback, the peripheral has **no** services! `peripheral.services` is empty.
It wouldn't have got this far if it didn't have the service, so what gives?
The `error` in this callback is also `nil`

Everything works fine when broadcasting the `CBPeripheral` on iOS 12

EDIT -----
Spoke too soon, it seems that now my iOS 12 device has started showing the same symptoms. After a short while the CBPeripheral doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by adding the `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` key when calling `startAdvertising` on the `CBPeripheralManager`. It seems this key is required if you want your `CBPeripheral` to keep broadcasting in the background. Apple docs fail to mention this.

Comment: Hello @Darren, for me this exact same problem continues to persist, despite giving the _CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey_


Code for initializing the peripheral advertising service:

`// create our characteristics
        let characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic.init(type: CBUUID(string: "12484b62-8da6-40b7-a54a-94ddf8f957a4"), properties: CBCharacteristicProperties.read, value: "dummy data to broadcast".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), permissions: CBAttributePermissions.readable)`

Comment: could you please contact me, or reply to my above comment.

the discovery does not work as expected and I get the same error as you, despite using the CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey

Comment: My issue was solved by adding the `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey` to the `CBPeripheralManager`. I suggest you start a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does your code still work now? i.e. can you discover a service from a peripheral that is backgrounded, connect to it, and read its characteristic?

I will start a new discussion and link this question, but if you are still interested on the topic, please reach me on my email..

Comment: Yes my code works fine now. I can leave an iPhone in standby for days and still discover and connect to a peripheral in the backgrounded app.